# JavaScript работает не корректно

Tags: javascript, html, css

сейчас я практикуюсь в сфере JavaScript, пробую всякие простые задачки.

В одной из задачек было указано создать кнопку которая будет убирать класс у объекта тем самым отображая его.

Идея была в том что по нажатии кнопки класс "hidden" у объекта убирается.
Но что то пошло не так, а именно ничего не происходит.

```js
var image = document.querySelector("image");
var open_image = document.querySelector(".open-button");

var openImage = function() {
  open_image.classList.remove("hidden");
};

if (open_image) {
  open_image.addEventListener("click", function() {
    openImage();
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.body {
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.open-button {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-button">Открыть</button>
<img src="C:\Users\Pupochek\Desktop\magazin\123.jpg" class="image hidden">
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: document.querySelector(".image"); забыли точку поставить. Это должно быть строкой селектора CSS

Comment: 1) open_image - это переменная,а не функция (для функции используется название с глагола) 2) open_image.classList.remove("hidden"); - вы убираете класс у кнопки, которого у нее нет 3) используйте let, const

Comment: Это полностью не помогло, но спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```
var image = document.querySelector(".image");
var open_image = document.querySelector(".open-button");

var openImage = function () {
  image.classList.remove("hidden");
};

if (open_image) {
  open_image.addEventListener("click", function () {
    openImage();
  });
}
```

Comment: Верного ответа так и не последовало.
Правильным ответом является изменение 9 и 10 строки на :
open_image.addEventListener("click", openImage);